# Permission denied trying to open gdb in emacs

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am getting error: 'Searching for program: permission denied, gdb' when i try to run `M-x gdb` in emacs on windows machine.  I have Mingw and it is in the emacs search path `(getenv "PATH")`.  When I open a shell in emacs I can run gdb from the shell no problem.  What causes this permission denied?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out with the help of this excellent [page](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html)

Emacs has variable `exec-path` that will automatically sync with "PATH" variable.  However, if you customize your "PATH" variable in emacs (i.e from within `init.el`), these changes won't be added to `exec-path`.  So, you have to manually set the `exec-path` to contain the directory with the gdb executable.  On the linked page there is some nice code to help keep the two paths in sync.